# crystal report push method not work

Tags: crystal-reports

I face a problem when using push method in CR version 10.5. I set the datasource for crystal report using dataset with 4 record in it. But when I display it out, it display all the record in my table instead of what I already selected.
Any one have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, with the push method, the data set you push replaces the one specified in the report. It sounds like you're pushing a data set with the wrong records.

Comment: i try to put the select statement from my code behind to report template, it work correctly.

Comment: In my report template, I using Add command to set the select statement in it.  Then from my system, I put the dataset as a datasource for the report.  I'm using ODBC to add this command.

Comment: As I understand it, then, you're using the pull method.